# How do I join multiple tables with Entity Framework Core and SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to join multiple tables in a database together. I'm using Entity Framework Core, SQLite and C#. Originally, the database contained only two tables which I joined using a navigational property and foreign key. It worked as expected.

However, when I tried to add more tables using the same process (eg foreign keys and navigational properties), VS Code would not compile. The error is

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0] Unable to start Kestrel.

I have deleted the new tables but I'm still getting the same error.

I have included the code here. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace GMS.Data.Repositories
{
    public class DatabaseContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyAccount> MyAccounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
      
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .UseSqlite("Filename=data.db");            
        }
        
        public void Initialise()
        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
}

namespace GMS.Data.Models
{
    public class MyAccount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public IList<Request> Requests { get; set; } = new List<Request>();
    }
}

namespace GMS.Data.Models
{
    public class Request
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Issue { get; set; }
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Resolution { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime ResolvedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        // Foreign key relating to MyAccount request owner
        public int MyAccountId { get; set; }

        public MyAccount MyAccount { get; set; } // navigation property
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hello, your error doesn't depend on table count. It sounds stupid, but can you reboot ur PC and try again?

Comment: You should normally never need to do joins in EF because EF will create `Include()` and Navigation Properties for you.

Comment: @Veritas "Unable to start Kestrel." is because _something else_ is failing (Kestrel is ASP.NET Core's built-in webserver: it has nothing to do with EF or databases!) - we can't help you until you post the **full** error details and address _that_ issue first.